# jQuery on('toggle') not working together

Tags: jquery

Wondering on how to achieve the toggle, its only deactivating the input "meta_website_url" on click but doesnot gets back.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="PostWebsite" class="calculate-total" checked="checked">
<input id="meta_website_url" type="text" name="meta[6]" value="">

$('body').on('click', '#PostWebsite', function(){
    if (!$(this).attr('checked') || $(this).attr('checked') == 'off'){       
       $(this).attr('checked','on');
       $("#meta_website_url").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'off'){
       $(this).attr('checked','off');
       $("#meta_website_url").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `$(this).is(':checked')` or `$(this).prop('checked')` and best `this.checked`

Comment: dont u think your else if should be like this `else if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'on'){` instead of `else if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'off'){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your `if` statement. You're not checking whether the `checked` attribute isn't set to "off" in the first statement. Your `if` statement effectively says: *if this is set to `off`, do this, otherwise if this is set to `off`, do this* - the latter will never be hit.

Change:

```
if (!$(this).attr('checked') || $(this).attr('checked') == 'off'){
                                                        ^^
```

To:

```
if (!$(this).attr('checked') || $(this).attr('checked') != 'off'){
```

As a side note, if you're using jQuery 1.8+ you should use [**`prop`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for boolean attributes: `$(...).prop('checked', true);`

Comment: checked valid value is "checked" or "" (empty string) http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

Comment: @Satpal actually anything works for checkedness, only an empty string will uncheck the control. Regardless, if `checked` is set to "off", this `if` statement will still work accordingly.

Comment: Storing on/off is not the purpose of checked property regardless  _anything works for checkedness_.

Answer (score 0):

Use the removeAttr(" ~~ ") method of Jquery.